# Selenium record and play back a css element

Tags: css, selenium, selenium-ide

When i try to playback a recorded script, in which there is a click on css drop down like thing and select an option from it, i got the following error:
"Element not found".

Here there is nothing like loading so that it takes some time and element is not visible. It's just a plain web page.

Please help me in resolving this issue and go on with the recorded script.

Answer (score 0):

Try invoking a [`mouseOver`](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-core/1.0/reference.html#mouseOver) command on the underlying element, that should give the dropdown menu a hint to appear and the element you're missing will be visible.

Comment: Thank u Mr.Slanec for the answer